# How to Check Status of more than one url in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hello team I have function that check url is down or UP

```
 public function checkSystem()
{
    $content = file_get_contents("http://policy.fetty.go.com/user/login");
    if (strpos($content, 'Fatal error') !== false)
    {
        echo("<span class='offline'>Down</span>");
    }
    else
    {
        echo("<span class='Up'>Up</span>");
    }
}
```

I want to be able to check more than one url please assist

Answer (score 1):

I would parameterize the url then call that method in a loop and return the status as the output of the function.  So something like this where you pass the parameter in as a parameter.

1 - This would be your function.  Reference this whereever you want to perform the task.

```
 public function checkSystem($url)
 {
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    if (strpos($content, 'Fatal error') !== false)
    {
        $status = "<span class='offline'>Down</span>"; 
    }
    else
    {
        $status = "<span class='Up'>Up</span>";
    }
    return $status;
 }
```

2 - Put your urls in an array like so:

```
$urls = array(‘https://web.whatsapp.com’, ‘https://google.com’);
```

3 - You could then pass that method in a loop like:

```
foreach ($urls as $url){
    checkSystem($url);
}
```

There is a more laravel way to perform this, but this would be how you perform this task against multiple urls.

Comment: sorry where do I put the two link like https://web.whatsapp.com/ and https://www.google.com/. then

Comment: You would place them in an array that you pass through the foreach loop like this:   $urls = array(‘https://web.whatsapp.com’, ‘https://www.google.com’);

Comment: I updated the answer with how to add the array, then how to pass that array to a loop.  I'd suggest spending some time on laracasts.  They offer free videos and should be able to build up your php and laravel knowledge.